# After pressing the login button my login_exec file doesnt re-direct

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

I'm just starting to learn some of the basic's of PHP and Mysql and how to implement what they are used for into some of my designs.

For the last couple of nights i've been trying to teach myself various registration and login forms to no avail. I've just found a tutorial which half has worked (The registration half) meaning i can use my form to submit my information and save it onto my database.

I've now moved onto the login section of the tutorial. And after carefully looking over the code i'm stuck where to go next!

Basically, i don't get any errors at all.

When submit is pressed after you enter your username and password it uses a separate .php document to query my database for my username and password and then to validate the information and should then redirect you to your home.php

However when submit is pressed all i get is a white screen.

If anyone could shed some light on my situation i would be greatful please find my code for my login_exec.php file below.

Any other information needed i will provide as soon as i can!

Thank you all ever so much.

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('connection.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$username = clean($_POST['username']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($username == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: Repairs.php");
    exit();
}

//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: home.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
        $errflag = true;
        if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            header("location: Repairs.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
} ?>
```

Comment: white screen of death, error checking is disabled or not displaying. also you are storing plain text passwords and using an depreciated db library

Comment: enable `error_reporting` if you see white page only

Comment: storing passwords in plaintext in your database is a hideous security vulnerability.

Comment: I would rather start learning mysqli or pdo instead of deprecated mysql_*

Comment: Marc i'm going to be adding hash salts once i've got it all working. Plus it's a blank database apart from my test user. Fabio mysqli is my next step, i'm just using this as a stepping stone to build on while i'm still getting my head round it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call `header("location: home.php");` **before** `session_write_close();`.

Comment: I've changed this, and also edited my error.ini file, now i get the error messages

Comment: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jaaronlewis/public_html/login_exec.php:2) in /home/jaaronlewis/public_html/login_exec.php on line 4

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/jaaronlewis/public_html/login_exec.php:2) in /home/jaaronlewis/public_html/login_exec.php on line 4
Warning: Cannot modify header infor - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jaaronlewis/public_html/login_exec.php:2) in /home/jaaronlewis/public_html/login_exec.php on line 68

Comment: Ok,you can use `ob_start()` before `session_start` and `ob_end_flush()` after `session_write_close` for skip this error.